# how to remove the empty area in the website

Tags: css, html

i have been doing this website but i got stuck at the point where the blusih grey blank space at the bottom of the screen refused to go.
i have moved the  of the page. Any ideas on how to fix that blank area ?

[image: this is the webpage]

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700);
body {
    background: #08121A;
    background-image: url('../img3.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #545B64;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/** element defaults **/

table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
th,
td {
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
th {
    color: #666;
    background: #141517 none repeat-x scroll left top;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>site titl</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `background-size: cover` instead.

Comment: yes, i had tried that too, but no luck :(

Comment: Please post all your code, also the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put `img {position: fix; left:0px; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;}`

and move the img as last element in body tag

in your case body will take height from all the elements in it. so if u put `img` - background always will take the height of body( this is calculate form all the elements in the body) ,so if you put as a tag `<img src='myimg'/>` will take space and don't forget to put img tag low `z-index`

Answer (score 2):

Body css is wrong. Try this:

```
background-size:cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your html code.

You must end your  tag before start before  tag. not end of  tag. so your html code will be like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>site titl</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>

Put here your body content

</body>   
</html>
```

Then follow the css.

```
.yourcssClass {position: fix; left:0px; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;}
```